# Docker link container - environment variables not being displayed

Tags: docker, spring-boot, boot2docker, dockerfile, docker-registry

Hello I am trying to link my containers following this guide:

https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/

I run `docker run -d --name mongodb devops-mongodb`

Then I run `docker run -d -P --name rest-api --link mongodb devops-rest-api`

To link my mongodb container to the rest-api container.

Then the documentation told me to do this to view the environment variables:

```
docker run --rm --name rest-api2 --link db:db devops-rest-api env
```

However, it does not print out the environment variables like shown in the docs.

I just get the STDOUT from my Spring Boot application.

What am I doing wrong?

Which environment variables are you expecting? If you don't set any non will be shown. It would help if you post your dockerfile here. I think what you want to do is to access mongo from your rest api, right? Then just define mongodb as the hostname of mongo in your rest-api configuration and it should work. BTW: in the second call you have an error cause you are not specifying mongodb but --link db:db. –  hrrgttnchml 6 hours ago

**EDIT 1**: @hrrgttnchml, I am expecting these environment variables, straight from the doc:

```
DB_PORT
DB_PORT_5432_TCP
DB_PORT_5432_TCP_PROTO
DB_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT
DB_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR
```

I don't think you have to create environment variables with the -e, -env flags. 
According to the docs, Docker creates them automatically when you link two containers:

```
Docker creates several environment variables when you link containers. Docker automatically creates environment variables in the target container based on the --link parameters. It will also expose all environment variables originating from Docker from the source container. These include variables from:

the ENV commands in the source container’s Dockerfile
the -e, --env and --env-file options on the docker run command when the source container is started
```

I may be wrong, however.

Here is my rest-api dockerfile: http://pastebin.com/3Ktbbr9n

MongoDB dockerfile: http://pastebin.com/iqyKm5UK

Both applications can be started when the containers are ran. Just don't know how to link them.

Yes, I want the rest-api to communicate with the mongodb database.

Since I'm running spring-boot for the rest-api, I can specify in my application.properties file the host and port of my mongodb server such as:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=192.168.99.100
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
```

So are you telling me to replace `192.168.99.100` `with mongodb`?

I'm also running the oracle box virtual machine on windows so the VM itself has an ip address, and when connecting to the container I have to use the machine's IP and NOT localhost, so that is where 192.168.99.100 is from. Correct?

**EDIT 2:** I have gotten the rest-api to communicate with the mongodb **without** container linking by just using the address of the VM along with the exposed port in the Dockerfile. So for mongodb it would be 192.168.99.100:27017, whereas for the rest-api it would be 192.168.99.100:8080.

**However**, this is impractical because the ip address is **hardcoded** into the rest-api class itself. So someone else will not be able to run the images in his container on his machine be cause the ip addresses won't match.

Now obviously the work around is to use container linking as the solution since the host and port are automatically updated in the /etc/hosts file when they change, leading us back to the original question of how to get container linking to work.

**EDIT 3:** Specifying `mongodb` as the hostname in the rest-api does work but only when the alias for the database is passed in for the link such as: `--link mongodb`

Comment: Which environment variables are you expecting? If you don't set any non will be shown. It would help if you post your `dockerfile` here. I think what you want to do is to access mongo from your rest api, right? Then just define *mongodb* as the hostname of mongo in your rest-api configuration and it should work. BTW: in the second call you have an error cause you are not specifying mongodb but `--link db:db`.

Comment: @hrrgttnchml see edit in question

Comment: Did you try to inspect your `rest-api` container and check for host entries using `docker exec rest-api2 host mongodb`? It should show an address with the internal docker ip of your mongo container – usually 172.x.x.x

Comment: Ahh yes this worked, that is the IP address that I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `devops-rest-api` have a `ENTRYPOINT` perhaps? Any command line parameters on your `docker run` will get passed to the entrypoint. Instead of specifying a command, try overriding with `--entrypoint env`.

Comment: devops-rest-api has the entrypoint of: ENTRYPOINT ["java,"-jar","rest-api.war"]

Comment: OK, so when you pass `env` to the run command it becomes `java -jar rest-api.war env`. This probably isn't what you were expecting.

Comment: If my answer helped, consider accepting it so this question is no longer listed under "Unanswered".